# What is the end of a product backlog?

Tags: agile

I'm trying to understand some of the implications/principles of Agile Product Development.

So with a single Product backlog that captures everything that is wanted of the product, I'm not entirely clear about where it ends.

- I've heard of software products that are released with "known bugs" (different to missing features). In principle, should there be a product backlog there, behind the scenes, that is live and well until every last bug is fixed?
- Does the product backlog exist for as long as the product exists? In which in the case of a mature product, the product backlog will have very little on it - but it is still there. But then couldn't / wouldn't every github project have a product backlog?
- Does a product backlog reach some point where it is "finished" and now it's operational, so code changes are "defects" and tracked in a different way, and there is no more Product backlog?

Where exactly does the product backlog end?

Comment: I've always been under the impression that the product backlog ends when the product ends.  If no further changes are wanted, no matter how low-priority, then chances are nobody is actually using the product anymore.  (Keep in mind that the efforts involved in retiring a product, such as replacing it or migrating its data to another system, are part of the backlog.  If they're done, the product is out of use.)

Comment: So basically the product backlog "dissappears" when the product is "decommissioned"?

Comment: That backlog is just a queue. A queue gets filled and drained. If it ever gets "empty", your team failed.

Comment: @Till - That sounds a bit too black and white. Let me try a fictitious  example: Lets say Microsoft decided to now stop support on Windows 7 as of 31 Dec 2013. then as of that date the Product Backlog doesn't exist.... does it? The product is end of life. It's not the team that's failed - it's just the product has been surpassed. Yes? No?

Comment: @Maxcot what you meant to say is that MS stopped supporting Windows as a whole, considering that they dont hire new teams for every version of their product. But ok, lets stick with that - then this would indeed mean that the product went entirely out of service and hence has failed - hence the team has failed to adapt to the market. You need to differentiate between versions and products! Windows still is a product by Microsoft and its backlog started when they stole it from Steve ;)... it will most likely not end too soon.

Comment: @Till - Ok, I understand your point. I'm just not totally sure I would equate a decision to abandon a product as a "team failure"... for me anyway, it just has a whole lot of other connotations. The very decision to abandon a product is in and of itself a decision to adapt, which is possibly a good thing.

Comment: @Maxcot in think by trying to understand this very point, you quickly get into false assumptions. Hence my black&white painting. Its easier to see it as a never ending queue. In the end, these are just models for attempting to draft a process (or even reality). As those are just models, they certainly are not exact in all aspects, hence there certainly are scenarios that defeat my extreme picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely possible for a Product Backlog to be empty, but that does not mean it has ended.  Usually, this is just an indication that bugs have not been logged yet, or the product owner is doing a poor job of planning for additional features.

If you are some one running a product company, and your product has no backlog items, that means you are likely missing vision as to how to keep your product evolving to stay ahead of competitors and reach new markets.

That being said, many agile software projects now run with a product backlog, when in reality this is just a project backlog.  Similarly, a release team may be running a product backlog that is actually the release backlog.  In these scenarios, it is very common for the backlog to 'end' as it can only live for the length of time up to the project or release completion.  The remaining items then fall back onto the true product backlog that spans multiple projects or releases.

Answer (score 2):

The product backlog never ends. Its like a alive organism, he is aways getting bigger while the system is alive. Even if the project get ready, the product backlog still alive.

You can see more here: [The product backlog is a living artifact](http://agilebench.com/blog/the-product-backlog-for-agile-teams)